# Hiding paper-menu when losing focus

Tags: javascript, polymer-1.0

I'm creating a paper-menu element that is displayed *via* a paper-menu-button. How do I get the menu to close when clicking outside the menu area? The online demo (Polymer website) dismisses correctly, but the demo with the components (via Bower) doesn't - and I can't see any difference in the code.

Anyone have any ideas?

```
<paper-menu-button>
    <paper-icon-button icon="more-vert" class="dropdown-trigger"></paper-icon-button>

    <paper-menu class="dropdown-content">
        <paper-item>One</paper-item>
        <paper-item>Two</paper-item>
        <paper-item>Three</paper-item>
    </paper-menu>
</paper-menu-button>
```

Comment: It's working for me... what's your environment?

Comment: I found the problem - the PolyDev Chrome plugin was causing the issue (and others).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The PolyDev Chrome plugin was causing the issue (and others).